# JS not loading properly for my rails website

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's a case.

I am using rails to make a website.

Now I have multiple pages, say **Home**, **About** and **Projects**.

I have created partials for header and footer and rendering them in **About** and **Projects** page.

For some reasons my sliders/carousels are not loading for my **Projects** page.

I am confused a bit about where should I place my all the `<scripts>` .

I mean should I keep them in the footer partial or should I keep them in **projects.html.erb** file.

PS: Sorry for a noobish question though.

Comment: You should be using Asset pipeline which is bulit-in with rails http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: Rails 4 introduce turbolinks for the page loading. If you enable carousels with a $(document).ready or equivalent, this will not load this on any page, just the first, or the page you do F5. You have to use `$(document).on('page:load');`

Comment: for all the common scripts,you can use a common.js file and dump the scripts and include it in application.js file to have them included throughout the application...for other non important or page specific scripts...use them inside the page using script tag...

Comment: so I did require all the js files, like say 

    `//= require_tree ./abc/js
    //= require_tree ./chart/js`

Now this is working for but certain parts of js are not loading for certain
Carousel/sliders

Comment: Inspect the page and check all the necessary js files are loaded. Are you using turbolinks?